# Why ffmpeg rotate video?

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I have installed `ffmpeg` on x32 Ubuntu 14.04 via `apt-get`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

My command to convert video to images is:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i $VIDEO_PATH -qscale:v 1 "frames/image%d.jpg"
```

But for some reason images are 480x640 instead of 640x480.

Why ffmpeg rotate video?

Comment: There is a rotation tag present. You can use `ffmpeg -loglevel warning -noautorotate -i $VIDEO_PATH -qscale:v 1 "frames/image%d.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Seems this option help `-vf "transpose=0"`.

Comment: Can you add a sentence to your answer to explain how/why that fixes the problem?  That will add to its educational value.  Thanks.  [From review queue](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/572148)

Comment: @fixer1234 not, sure I figure out it by experimenting, by trying to rotate video back.